# Check isAdmin in Next 13 on the Client Side with Client Component?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I am using [Lucia Auth](https://lucia-auth.com) for authentication.

This function returns back the `session` object:

#### app/auth/lucia.ts

```
export const getPageSession = cache(async () => {
    const authRequest = auth.handleRequest("GET", context)
    const session = await authRequest.validate()

    return session
})
```

#### app/dashboard/admin.tsx

```
"use client"

import React from "react"
import { redirect } from "next/navigation"
import NextImg from "next/image"
import ky, { KyResponse } from "ky"

import { getPageSession } from "@/app/auth/lucia"
import { BASE_URL } from "@/app/lib/constants"

const Admin = async () => {
    const [admin, setAdmin] = React.useState(false)

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const fetchAdmin = async () => {
            const res: KyResponse & { isAdmin: boolean } = await ky.get(`${BASE_URL}/api/admin`).json()
            setAdmin(res.isAdmin)
        }
        fetchAdmin()
    }, [])

    const session = await getPageSession()

    if (!session && !admin) redirect("/login")

    return (
        <div className="isolate bg-slate-900 text-white">
            ...
        </div>
    )
}

export default Admin
```

The first check is to check if `session` exists because only logged-in users can access the page. It works completely fine.

And the second check is to check if its an `admin` because only admin can access the page. This doesn't work.

I get this error:

> You're importing a component that needs next/headers. That only works in a Server Component but one of its parents is marked with "use client", so it's a Client Component.

The `getPageSession` is a server-side check and the `React.useEffect` is a client call to the api that returns a json with a boolean like `{ isAdmin: false }` or `{ isAdmin: true }`

How do I perform both checks without getting an error? I get too many errors regarding using Server Things in Client Component & the likes.

Ideally, I'd like a common function called `isAdmin` that returns if someone is an admin or not. And if they are not, then redirect. If they are, then show the page.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Not sure if its the best way to do it but here it is.

I created a Client Component to check if someone is an admin:

#### components/dashboard/AdminComponent.tsx

**This solution doesn't work. I bet I am using `useEffect` wrong somehow which can be fixed but the alternate solution below works fine.**

```
"use client"

import React from "react"
import { redirect } from "next/navigation"
import ky, { KyResponse } from "ky"

import { BASE_URL } from "@/app/lib/constants"

export const AdminComponent = () => {
    const [admin, setAdmin] = React.useState(false)

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const fetchAdmin = async () => {
            const res: KyResponse & { isAdmin: boolean } = await ky.get(`${BASE_URL}/api/admin`).json()
            setAdmin(res.isAdmin)
        }
        fetchAdmin()
    }, [])

    if (!admin) redirect("/dashboard")

    return null
}
```

Then, I imported the Client Component into a Server Component.

#### pages/admin.tsx

```
import React from "react"
import { redirect } from "next/navigation"

import { getPageSession } from "@/app/auth/lucia"
import { AdminComponent } from "@/app/components/dashboard/AdminComponent"

const Admin = async () => {
    const session = await getPageSession()

    if (!session) redirect("/login")

    return (
        <div className="isolate bg-slate-900 text-white">
            ...
        </div>
    )
}

export default Admin
```

I also rewrote `AdminComponent` as:

```
"use client"

import React from "react"
import { redirect } from "next/navigation"
import ky, { KyResponse } from "ky"

import { BASE_URL } from "@/app/lib/constants"

const fetchAdmin = React.cache(async () => {
    const res: KyResponse & { isAdmin: boolean } = await ky.get(`${BASE_URL}/api/admin`).json()
    return res.isAdmin
})

export const AdminComponent = () => {
    const admin = React.use(fetchAdmin())

    if (!admin) redirect("/dashboard")

    return null
}
```

This looks much cleaner but not a common pattern as of now.

Would love to know if there is a more simpler or cleaner solution.

**Edit:**

Found a much better solution.

#### components/dashboard/AdminComponent.tsx

```
"use client"

import React from "react"
import { redirect } from "next/navigation"

import { useAdminStatus } from "@/app/hooks/useAdminStatus"

// eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name
export const AdminComponent = React.memo(() => {
    const { data, error, isLoading } = useAdminStatus()

    if (isLoading) return null
    if (error) return <span className="text-slate-500">Failed to load `AdminComponent`</span>

    if (!data.isAdmin) redirect("/dashboard")

    return null
})
```

#### hooks/useAdminStatus.tsx

```
import useSWRImmutable from "swr/immutable"

const fetcher = (...args: [any]) => fetch(...args).then((res) => res.json())

export const useAdminStatus = () => {
    const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWRImmutable(`/api/admin`, fetcher)

    return {
        data,
        error,
        isLoading,
    }
}
```